How can I count the number of visible objects in a rendered image?
I used to do this on blender2.78c+ubuntu20.04(cuda11.8+4090), but it will error after process around 700+ images.
CUDA: failed to run compiler to retrieve version CUDA nvcc compiler version could not be parsed.

  for i, obj in enumerate(blender_objects):
    old_materials.append(obj.data.materials[0])
    bpy.ops.material.new()
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
    mat.name = 'Material_%d' % i
    while True:
      r, g, b = [random.random() for _ in range(3)]
      if (r, g, b) not in object_colors: break
    object_colors.add((r, g, b))
    mat.diffuse_color = [r, g, b]
    mat.use_shadeless = True
    obj.data.materials[0] = mat
  bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

I try to move to blender4.1, however I didn't find the substitute for material.use_shadeless in blender4.1. I wonder if there is a better way to make the number of colors in the rendered image is the same as the number of objects(If all visible)

Please use the according tags on your question when it's about python / scripting.

This looks like this script is using the old legacy Blender Internal Renderer which has been removed since version 2.80.
I suggest you use the Cycles renderer with the Cryptomatte "Object" pass, this will render a pass with a different color for each object. You don't even need to worry about materials with this solution. Then get the Cryptomatte output and save the image in post-processing after rendering in the Compositing editor.
You can use a single sample to reduce render times.


Note I don't think this supports transparency.

thanks for answering! unfortunately I can only operate blender through script, do you know how to do it through python?
